# Check if there are a list of words contained in a string

Tags: javascript, performance

Let's consider the following string `text` "I just tried the new burgers in burger land!" and the following array of strings ["eat", "burger", "fries"]

What I want is to know if any of the words of `text` exist in the array, but in a optimized way... not just with two for-loops...

Any ideas?

Comment: `for loops` is the most optimized way

Comment: Actually, hardcoding the result is the most optimized way :P at least for one example, anyway...

Comment: [.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this via regular expression by joining the array to create a string.

RegEx References

- [Word Boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) – Allows you to perform a "whole words only" search
- [Non-Capturing Groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) – This is a group that is not stored in memory to be referenced later on.
- [Pipe Symbol](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) – Search for the literal text

Once the RegEx string is created via JavaScript it looks like this (string escaping removed):

```
\b(?:eat|burger|fries)\b
```

```js
const str = 'I just tried the new burgers in burger land!'
const arr = ['eat', 'burger', 'fries']

// "\b" This is a word boundary - Allows you to perform a "whole words only" search
// "(?:xxx)" This is a non-capturing group. It's not stored in memory to be referenced later on.
// 'arr.join()' creates the following string: "eat|burger|fries"
console.log(str.match(new RegExp(`\\b(?:${arr.join('|')})\\b`, 'ig')))
```

If needing to escape regex is a concern, you can do it by [escaping special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex). and mapping over the array of words that need to be tested.

```js
const str = 'I just tried the new burgers in burger land!'
const arr = ['eat', 'burger', 'fries', '(']
const esc = s => s.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')

console.log(str.match(new RegExp(`\\b(?:${arr.map(esc).join('|')})\\b`, 'ig')))
```

Comment: I guess you can just drop the `\\b` in join. simply `join('|')` will be enough as you already have `word boundaries` at start and end.

Comment: That picks up `burger` and `burgers`... not sure if that is the desired result.

Comment: That can be handled with capturing group. `\\b(?:${arr.join('|')})\\b` you can try like this

Comment: Anyways nice answer +1

Comment: This works only as long as none of your strings has any special RegExp characters. Consider `arr = ['(']`.

Comment: That can be handled by implementing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex

Comment: Hi @GetOffMyLawn and thanks for your answer! Could you please explain the RegExp part, because I haven't used it before? What does each character do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well the most optimized way IMO is to have `wordsTest` as object instead of array so lookup becomes `O(1)` operation. and than you can use `filter` to get any matching value.

```js
const test = "I just tried the new burgers in burger land!";
const wordsTest = {"eat":1, "burger":1, "fries":1}

const wordsInString = (test) => test.split(' ').filter(e => wordsTest[e] )

console.log(wordsInString(test))
console.log(wordsInString('No matching words'))
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Array#Filter` and `indexOf()`.

1. `Array#Filter` is filter the array based `index` match in string
2. use `toLowerCase()` for match case sensitive string

```js
var a ="I just tried the new burgers in burger land!";
var arr = ["eat", "burger", "fries"];

var res = arr.filter(i=> a.toLowerCase().indexOf(i.toLowerCase()) > -1)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I like the way you used filter